# ognl.ExpressionSyntaxException

Tags: java, spring, jsp, struts2, ognl

i am finding ognl.ExpressionSyntaxException: Malformed OGNL expression: Add Customer [ognl.ParseException: Encountered "  "Customer "" at line 1, column 5.
Was expecting one of:`<EOF> 
    "," ...
    "=" ...
    "?" ...
    "||" ...
    "or" ...
    "&&" ...
    "and" ...
    "|" ...
    "bor"`

i am using the code in jsp like
`<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>

  <head>

    <title>titlePager</title>

  </head>

  <body>

    <s:form action="addsome">

    <s:textfield label="Customer ID:" name="customerID" size="15" maxlength="10" />

</s:form>

  </body>

</html>`

Answer (score 0):

I think your code example is incomplete. First, I don't see a submit button in your form and the exception indicates that the malformed OGNL exception is "Add Customer", which seems like what you would put as the label on a submit button.

Make sure that you specified that for the correct attribute on the submit button.